# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') Need help navigating

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was able to navigate to my Profile component before I decided to make the Header its own HeaderComponent.

Adding `navigation={this.props.navigation}` on the HeaderComponent gets rid of the error, however it won't navigate to the Profile component.

App.js

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  // route configurator
  {
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
    },
    TripDetail: {
      screen: TripDetail,
    },
    Moment: {
      screen: Moment,
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
    },
    Discover: {
      screen: Discover,
    },
  },
  // options
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  }
);
```

Header Component

```
export default class HeaderComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button
            transparent
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
          >
            <Icon name='menu' />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Roam</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Button transparent
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
          >
            <Icon name='person' />
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
    );
  }
}
```

Rendering the headercomponent

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'}}>
        <HeaderComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            <Trip />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Moment />

          </View>
        </ScrollView>

      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take at tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You have a StackNavigator and you are trying to open up Drawer. You need to have a DrawerNavigator for that. Where do you use that Headercomponent?

Comment: I use my header component in my dashboard comment that I posted. I'm not quite sure what the problem is but I am using the drawer and the stacknavigator